GoogleAuthClient signIn() Returns Null IntentSender in Firebase Authentication
I'm implementing Google Sign-In with Firebase Authentication using One Tap sign-in in my Android app. However, when calling signIn() in my custom GoogleAuthClient, the IntentSender is returning null.
class GoogleAuthClient(
    private val context: Context,
    private val oneTapClient: SignInClient
) {
    private val auth = Firebase.auth

    suspend fun signIn(): IntentSender? {
        val result = try {
            oneTapClient.beginSignIn(buildSignInRequest()).await()
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            e.printStackTrace()
            null
        }
        return result?.pendingIntent?.intentSender
    }

    private fun buildSignInRequest(): BeginSignInRequest {
        return BeginSignInRequest.builder()
            .setGoogleIdTokenRequestOptions(
                GoogleIdTokenRequestOptions.builder()
                    .setSupported(true)
                    .setServerClientId(context.getString(R.string.server_client_id))
                    .setFilterByAuthorizedAccounts(true)
                    .build()
            ).build()
    }
}

The signIn() method is returning null for result?.pendingIntent?.intentSender. I’ve set up Firebase and Google Sign-In, including the server_client_id in strings.xml.  What I’ve Checked: Firebase and Google Sign-In are configured correctly in the Google Cloud Console. server_client_id is set correctly. SHA-1 and SHA-256 fingerprints are added to the Firebase project.
